# statistic print in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tuples, `[(falseName, realName, positionOfMistake)]` e.g.:

```
[('Milter', 'Miller', 4),
 ('Manton','Manson',4), 
 ('Moller', 'Miller', 2)]
```

and I need to write a function that returns:

```
Miller:
    Milter: 0.50
    Moller: 0.50
Manson:
    Manton: 1.00
```

I was thinking:

```
def nameStatistics(nameList):
    D={}
    for tup in nameList
        if tup[1] not in D:
            D[tup[1]]={}
            if tup[0] not in D[tup[1]]:
                D[tup[1]][tup[0]]=0
            D[tup[1]][tup[0]] += 1
            print tup[1]+":\n\t"+tup[0]
```

But from that I get:

```
  Miller:
        Milter 
  Miller:     
        Moller
  Manson:
        Manton
```

Comment: For readability's sake, you should use `for falseName, realName, positionOfMistake in nameList:` rather than indexing the tuple.

Comment: Also, consider using an `collections.Counter` object for your data structure rather than a dict of dicts.  It will be cleaner and you won't need to initialize counts to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not building your dictionary correctly, because your indentation is wrong in several places. Also, your print-statement does not refer to the dictionary you build. Try this:

```
def nameStatistics(nameList):
    D={}
    for firstName, lastName, unused in nameList:
        if lastName not in D:
            D[lastName]={}
        if firstName not in D[lastName]:
            D[lastName][firstName] = 0
        D[lastName][firstName] += 1
    # only print after all tuples are processed
    for lastName, stats in D.iteritems():
        print lastName + "\n"
        for firstName, frequency in stats.iteritems():
            print "\t{0}:  {1}\n".format(firstName, frequency/float(len(stats)))
```

You can simplify this further by using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def nameStatistics(nameList):
    D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for firstName, lastName, unused in nameList:
        D[lastName][firstName] += 1
    # only print after all tuples are processed
    for lastName, stats in D.iteritems():
        print lastName + "\n"
        for firstName, frequency in stats.iteritems():
            print "\t{0}:  {1}\n".format(firstName, frequency/float(len(stats)))
```